# Every Factor-Critical graph is bridgeless.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every factor-critical graph is bridgeless.

I can't get the definition or any results that relate these two concepts, any hint is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you begin by defining the terms "factor-critical" and "bridgeless"?

Answer (score 1):

Definitions: A graph $G$ is said to be *factor-critical* if $\forall v \in V(G)$, $G-v$ has a perfect matching ( believe *hypomatchable* is another term used.) Note $G$ is necessarily of odd order. (By order I mean $|V(G)|$)

A graph $G$ is said to be *bridgeless* if it has no cut edge. In other words, the removal of any one edge will not result in an increase in the number of components of $G$.

Now to the statement at hand:

> If $G$ is a factor-critical graph then $G$ is bridgeless.

Proof: Let $G$ be a factor critical graph. Suppose $G$ is not bridgeless, i.e. $G$ has a cut edge $e=uv$. Note that $G$ is necessarily of odd order. We remove $e$ to obtain $G' = G-e$, where $G'$ has two components $H_1$ of odd order and $H_2$ of even order (since odd $=$ odd $+$ even.) Now we have (WLOG) $u \in H_1$ and $v \in H_2$.

Can you find the contradiction?

> The removal of $v$ gives a graph $G'' = G-v$ with $H_1$, an odd component, and some other components. But since $G''$ has an odd component, it cannot have a perfect matching, contradicting our factor-critical assumption.